# How to use proxy for get dns records

Tags: go, proxy, dns

I have some problem.

I need to use proxy for get dns records via 8.8.8.8

But I had some error in my code.

Cannot use &dialer (type *proxy.Dialer) as type *net.Dialer in field value

My code is:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/miekg/dns"
    "golang.org/x/net/proxy"
)

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    dialer, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", "12.34.56.78:8085", nil, proxy.Direct)
    checkErr(err)
    dnsServer := "8.8.8.8:53"
    c := dns.Client{
        Net: "tcp",
        Dialer: &dialer,
    }
    m := dns.Msg{}
    m.SetQuestion("google.com.", dns.TypeA)
    a, _, err := c.Exchange(&m, dnsServer)
    checkErr(err)
    for _, ans := range a.Answer {
        log.Println(ans.(*dns.A).A)
    }
}
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I am trying to use TCP for dns request.

Comment: It would be simpler to use DNS over TLS or DNS over HTTPS. Various public resolvers offers these. Also when you obfuscate IP addresses please use guidance from RFC5737 instead of whatever you imagine.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, thank you for good idea. The problem resolved.